# Prevent Bootstrap Modal from showing using ajax error

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, modal-dialog

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent the Modal from showing up when an ajax call returns an error. I've seen a few posts here already that use

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

but I couldn't manage to make that work. My ajax call looks as follow

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",    
    error: function (e) {

        //show error message
            $('#alertdone').removeClass('hidden');

    },
    //if ajax call is successful populate form fields and hide error message
    success: function (data) {

        //hides the error message
        $('#alertdone').addClass('hidden');

    }


});
```

Thanks

Comment: Where's the modal code? When is it going to show up?

Comment: shouldn't you be doing `$('#alertdone').addClass('hidden');` ?

Comment: The Modal shows up when a button is clicked.

@DaniyalNasir 

I'm not sure what you mean? I'm doing
    $('#alertdone').addClass('hidden');

already.

Comment: I assume that the AJAX code is related to the modal? In other words, when the AJAX is successful the modal will be shown. The solution then would be to simply not show the modal when the AJAX is unsuccessful. This sounds a bit too simple, doesn't it?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware

Right now the Modal gets called regardless of the ajax answer. I pass an id and and a button name as data, and depending on the value of the button name it opens a different modal, or rather, the content of the modal is different.

Comment: It's still not clear what is going on. If I assume that your're talking about the AJAX call, from your code, returning the button name and id, and it is the button that opens the modal, then you could disable the button on failure of the AJAX. That way the user cannot open the modal when the AJAX fails.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware

I'm sorry about the confusion.
The ajax call only happens after the button is clicked. The whole ajax call is inside   $("ID").click(function () {

so i can't disable the button. I pass the button name and an id. The id is the selected checkbox. If the user does not select a checkbox, the ajax call will return error since the id i want to pass doesn't exist.
I want to prevent the modal from showing up when that happens.

Comment: I read that three times, and still cannot make sense of it. By now it is clear that the code in your question should have make clear what the relation between the modal and the AJAX code is. Only then we've got something to talk about.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware

It works now using the answer Daniyal Nasir provided. I'll try to give more detail in future questions as to avoid confusion. Nonetheless, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am assuming that you need to hide (don't show) the modal if the AJAX calls fails (since there's a difference between ajax call failing and returning error from server side).**

For that you need to remove your `data-attribute` from HTML and do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",    
    error: function (e) {
        $('#alertdone').removeClass('hidden');
        $("modal_selector").modal('hide');
    },
    //if ajax call is successful populate form fields and hide error message
    success: function (data) {
        $('#alertdone').addClass('hidden');
        $("modal_selector").modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand your confusion. We don't know if the alert was shown, to start with, or not. But if it was hidden, then it should be shown when an error occurs.

Comment: Ah, I see, you assume that `#alertdone` is the modal. I don't think the question makes that clear. It could just be a box with text in the normal page flow.

Comment: Are your triggering the modal thru HTML custom attributes ?

Comment: The error message is unrelated to the Modal.
It's just a div with an error message that i hide or show.

I call the modal through a button in HTML, using data- attribute.

Comment: @DaniyalNasir

I should've mentioned that i've tried this already. But using it shows the modal for a brief moment, and then makes it disappear, which just doesn't look good.

Comment: you need remove the data-attributes and trigger it only from jquery.

Comment: @DaniyalNasir

That makes sense. I'll give it a go.

Thanks

Comment: Alright, consider accepting it as answer if it works or let me know in case of error/problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide/ show modal depending on condition use `modal()`

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",    
    error: function (e) {

        //show error message
            $('#alertdone').removeClass('hidden');
           $("Your_modal_id").modal('hide');

    },
    //if ajax call is successful populate form fields and hide error message
    success: function (data) {

        //hides the error message
        $('#alertdone').addClass('hidden');
           $("Your_modal_id").modal('show');

    }


});
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that i've tried this already.
But using it shows the modal for a brief moment, and then makes it disappear, which just doesn't look good.